# Error when using gcc (minGW) to build .exe with same filename?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, filenames

I've been trying to build another .exe file with the same name in minGW,  but everytime I run the command: `gcc file.c -o file.exe` I run into the problem of:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
cannot open output file main.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But, if I run the same command with `gcc file.c -o file2.exe` the command executes fine, and I can compile my C code. **Is there any way to build .exe files with the same name?**

My C code is a simple "hello world":

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
   printf("hello world");
}
```

Thank you!

Updates:

- checked task manager, but the .exe is not running in the background.
- I have writing permission to the folder
- My antivirus doesn't seem to be the problem
- I can edit and delete the file.exe "by hand". I used command line to rename it to file1.exe, but when I tried to rename it back to file.exe I got an "access denied". Even though I am running command line as an admin.
- file.exe is just a generic name to ask this question instead of giving the 
  name of my project

Comment: Is the `file.exe` still running when you try to build it? Perhaps somewhere in the background? Windows is sometimes (most of the time?) a strange system...

Comment: @the-busybee thanks for the comment! I opened my task manager and made sure nothing name file.exe was running on the background... I triple checked... and nothing.

Comment: Turn off your antivirus, and check that there is write permission to the directory for the user that the compiler is running as

Comment: You can use [Sysinternals Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to inspect the actual error code given by the operating system for the attempt to open the file

Comment: @M.M Your ideas are good, however, I had never problems with antivirus, and I had to work a lot with different ones. :-} I suspect something else.

Comment: Are you able to delete the `file.exe` "by hand" on the command line? Are you able to delete it "by hand" in the Explorer? Or to rename it?

Comment: you claim the command was `gcc file.c -o file.exe`, but the output shows it tried to build `main.exe`, are you sure that was the command?

Comment: Thank you for comments the busybee and M.M. - I have permission to edit - My antivirus doesn't seem to be the problem - I can edit and delete the file.exe "by hand", but interesting thing is that I can't rename it to what it was before! - file.exe is just a generic name to ask this question instead of giving the name of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this question: [Command prompt access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48755502/12935499)

I saw a comment that helped:

> Noting C:> in your question, your Windows root drive is usually write protected, you may find that simply changing directory to somewhere without that protection may also help. – Compo

And indeed, having my file in the root drive was the problem. Sorry I didn't provide enough information for those who helped. But thank you so much for the help!